# Do one-relator groups satisfy Haagerup property?

Tags: gr.group-theory

The question is in the title:

> Do one-relator groups satisfy Haagerup property?

I think the answer is known at least in some specific cases, but is the problem completely solved?

Comment: Most 1-relator groups are known to be free-by-(virtually solvable) (which implies Haagerup). It sounds plausible to me that 1-relator groups all have this property.

Comment: @YCor, do you know if this holds for Baumslag's famous example $\langle a,b\mid a^{(a^b)}=a^2\rangle$?

Comment: @HJRW good question, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the problem is not solved, but much is known. The canonical reference is
the suggestively named Groups with Haagerup property: Gromov's a-T-menability, by Cherix, Cowling, Jolissant, Julig, Valette. See, in particular, Theorem 6.3.1 and Chapter 7